# Using CloudFront with EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

First time doing this so I have some questions and hope people can help me out here.

I have a brand new EC2 and domain (e.g. domain.com) and I want to add CloudFront to it. Would like to check if the following steps is correct.

1. Point root domain A record to EC2 server IP
2. Create a subdomain **www**.domain.com
3. Create a new distribution in CloudFront
4. Set origin domain in CloudFront distribution to root domain (domain.com)
5. Add CloudFront domain name as CNAME for subdomain [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)
6. Set server redirect all root domain to subdomain [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

Question 1: I wanted to check if the above is the correct setup for CDN and if I have missed any steps.

Question 2: The part I'm most unsure of is my naked domain since it can only accept A record. Would pointing it to my origin IP (EC2) and then doing a server redirect to subdomain [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) be the best solution?

My setup is a simple single EC2 server and a domain. It will host just 1 website that need to be on CloudFront.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to point your domain to the EC2 server (Step #1). Instead, point the CNAME to the CloudFront distribution, tell CloudFront about your [custom domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html), and point the CloudFront origin to the Elastic IP address of the EC2 server.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, thanks!

Apologies for my dummy question but what will happen when people type in domain.com in their browser? Without first step, wouldn't that not return anything?

Comment: Users browse to `domain.com`. This goes to a DNS service and a `CNAME` record points it to the CloudFront DNS name. CloudFront receives the request, extracts the original domain name, finds the matching distribution, sends the request to the distribution which sends it to the Elastic IP address, which points to the EC2 instance, which receives the request.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, understand but I've seen many articles and also DNS providers saying that a CNAME cannot be placed at root domain level (https://ns1.com/resources/cname).

"A CNAME cannot be placed at the root domain level, because the root domain is the DNS Start of Authority (SOA) which must point to an IP address. CNAME records must point to another domain name, never to an IP address."

Only a few DNS providers allow CNAME at root domain level. I'm using GoDaddy.
https://university.webflow.com/lesson/set-the-root-domain-as-the-default-domain-on-ssl-hosting

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah yes. If you want to point the root level domain, you can use Route 53. It can create an A-Record that is an Alias to a CloudFront distribution. It means you would need to configure GoDaddy to point to Amazon Route 53's nameservers. See: [Routing traffic to an Amazon CloudFront web distribution by using your domain name - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)

Comment: Ok, that make sense and understand. Will check that out.

Understand DNS would resolve faster that being server re-routed.

Just wondering would doing the 6 steps (in my initial main question) work too or would that have any adverse repercussions down the road?

Thank you for your explanation and certainly appreciate it!

Comment: I don't understand #6, but the others will work. Try it and see!

Comment: Actually you're right!! #6 won't work as root domain is the origin and cannot be redirected else edge servers will never be able to fetch from origin (as it's always being redirected). I'll explore Route53. Thank you!